# Saving layers from ArcSDE to layer file using ArcMap

Tags: arcpy, layers, enterprise-geodatabase, layer-file, arcgis-10.8

I have an MXD with layers sourced to SDE feature classes. I am trying to save the layers as layer files. However, I can't get `arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management` to do its job. Here's the code I use in the Python window of the MXD:

```
>>> mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument ("current")
>>> lyrs = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers (mxd)
>>> loc = r"c:\Work\MXD Templates\Layers"
>>> for lyr in lyrs:
...     try: src = lyr.dataSource
...     except: continue
...     if not "DesiredSDE" in src: continue
...     name = src.split (".") [-1]
...     print name
...     outLyr = os.path.join (loc, name + ".lyr")
...     arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management(lyr, outLyr)
...     
LYRNAME
Runtime error  Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<string>", line 8, in <module>   File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.8\arcpy\arcpy\management.py", line 7709, in SaveToLayerFile     raise e ExecuteError: ERROR 000840: The value is not a Layer.  
>>>
```

The code fails on all layers in the MXD. I've tried `arcpy.SaveToLayerFile_management(lyr.name, outLyr)` but the results were the same.

Comment: If you run the same code from IDLE without the try/except statements can you get a more useful error message?

Comment: Does your layer support DATASOURCE? If not, your src variable won't have a valid value. Check the supports method [documentation](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-mapping/layer-class.htm)  and use the "DATASOURCE" layer property.